# Who manufactured the 737 MAX flap track fairings?

Tags: boeing-737, flaps, aircraft-manufacturer, aircraft-production

I can't seem to find the information online, would anyone of you know where / by who the flap track fairing for the B737 MAX is produced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fairing assemblies are made by Boeing itself. From [ATS](https://www.atsmro.com/component-repair/capabilities-search/):

[image: FTF]